# When would you need multiple servers to host one web application?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is that called "clustering" of servers? When a web request is sent, does it go through the main server, and if the main server can't handle the extra load, then it forwards it to the secondary servers that can handle the load? Also, is one "server" that's up and running the application called an "instance"?

Answer (score 4):

> [...] Is that called "clustering" of servers?

Clustering is indeed using transparently multiple nodes that are seen as a unique entity: the cluster. Clustering allows you to *scale*: you can spread your load on all the nodes and, if you need more power, you can add more nodes (short version). Clustering allows you to be *fault tolerant*: if one node (physical or logical) goes down, other nodes can still process requests and your service remains available (short version).

> When a web request is sent, does it go through the main server, and if the main server can't handle the extra load, then it forwards it to the secondary servers that can handle the load?

In general, this is the job of a dedicated component called a "load balancer" (hardware, software) that can use many algorithms to balance the request: round-robin, FIFO, LIFO, load based...

In the case of EC2, you previously had to load balance with round-robin DNS and/or [HA Proxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/). See [Introduction to Software Load Balancing with Amazon EC2](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1639). But for some time now, Amazon has launched load balancing and auto-scaling (beta) as part of their EC2 offerings. See [Elastic Load Balancing](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/).

> Also, is one "server" that's up and running the application called an "instance"?

Actually, an instance can be many things (depending of who's speaking): a machine, a virtual machine, a server (software) up and running, etc.

In the case of EC2, you might want to read [Amazon EC2 Instance Types](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/).

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a real example:**

<sup>This specific configuration is hosted at RackSpace in their Managed Colo group.</sup>

Requests pass through a Cisco Firewall.  They are then routed across a Gigabit LAN to a [Cisco CSS 11501 Content Services Switch](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/contnetw/ps792/ps4949/index.html) (eg Load Balancer).  The Load Balancer matches the incoming content to a content rule, handles the SSL decryption if necessary, and then forwards the traffic to one of several back-end web servers.

Each 5 seconds, the load balancer requests a URL on each webserver.  If the webserver fails (two times in a row, IIRC) to respond with the correct value, that server is not sent any traffic until the URL starts responding correctly.

Further behind the webservers is a MySQL master / slave configuration.  Connections may be mad to the master (for transactions) or to the slaves for read only requests.

Memcached is installed on each of the webservers, with 1 GB of ram dedicated to caching. Each web application may utilize the cluster of memcache servers to cache all kinds of content.

Deployment is handled using rsync to sync specific directories on a management server out to each webserver.  Apache restarts, etc.. are handled through similar scripting over ssh from the management server.

The amount of traffic that can be handled through this configuration is significant.  The advantages of easy scaling and easy maintenance are great as well.

Answer (score 1):

For clustering, any web request would be handled by a load balancer, which being updated as to the current loads of the server forming the cluster, sends the request to the least burdened server. As for if it's an instance.....I believe so but I'd wait for confirmation first on that.

You'd' need a very large application to be bothered with thinking about clustering and the "fun" that comes with it software and hardware wise, though. Unless you're looking to start or are already running something big, it wouldn't' be anything to worry about.

Comment: If you think that the application may become big, it is a good idea to start with a framework that you know can scale to clusters even if you don't take advantage of it to begin with

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to learn this stuff as someone not from a technical background, and you guys provided a great explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be required for clustering. Typically as the load goes up you might find yourself with a frontend server that does url rewriting, https if required and caching with squid say. The requests get passed on to multiple backend servers - probably using cookies to associate a session with a particular backend if necessary. You might have the database on a separate server also.

I should add that there are other reasons why you might need multiple servers, for instance there may be a requirement that the database is not on the frontend server for security reasons

Comment: Thank you gnibbler! Really appreciate the concise tutorial on it. Thank you.